# How to configure "BingSearch" in ServiceConnect?

Tags: serviceexecute

I run the following commands in Mathematica.

```
service=ServiceConnect["BingSearch"]
```

It opens up a dialog box with link to `BingSearch`. The link takes me to my azure portal (https://portal.azure.com/#home).

I click `All services` then select `Marketplace` and in its search bar I search for `"Bing"` and get the list containing the following:

- Bing Maps API for Enterprise
- Bing Custom Search
- Bing Spell Check v7
- Bing Search v7
- Bing Entity Search
- Bing Autosuggest v7
- ...

I choose `Bing Search v7` and click create and follow the wizard to deploy the API.

I click my deployed API and it says `Congratulations! Your keys are ready.`.

I have Azure subscription with `Subscription ID` in the following format:

```
"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

If I go to manage keys section of my API, I see the following information:

- NAME: "BingSearchAPI" <-- This is the name I gave when deploying the API
- KEY 1: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
- KEY 2: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Now going back to the `ServiceConnect` dialog box, it asks for my `Subscription Key` what should i put here? My Azure `Subscription ID` or API `KEY 1` or API `KEY 2`.

Next on sending a query like:

```
ServiceExecute[
    service,
    "Search",{
        "Query"->"NASA",
        "Site"->"www.google.com/*",
        MaxItems->2,
        "SearchType"->"Web"
    }
]
```

I get another dialog box which says:

You are attempting to read from the domain:

```
...vadq.cloudapp.net
```

The server is requesting authentication.

(These values are kept for this session only.)

Username: [...]

Password: [...]

What username or password it is requesting here?

Also did I choose the wrong API. Should I have chosen `Bing Custom Search` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now I can confirm that the API is indeed `Bing Search v7` and not `Bing Custom Search`. I went into the directory "..\SystemFiles\Components\BingSearch\Kernel" and looked at the file "BingSearch.m" and found the following function

```
bingsearchdata["RawSearch"] :=
    {
    "URL"                -> (ToString@StringForm["https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/`1`", #]&),
    "HTTPSMethod"        -> "GET",
    "Parameters"        -> {"count", "offset", "q", "responseFilter", "safeSearch"},
    "PathParameters"    -> {"SearchTypePath"},
    "RequiredParameters"-> {"SearchTypePath"},
    "ResultsFunction"    -> BSFormatResults
    }
```

We can see that the end-point URL it is using is `` "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/`1`" ``.

On the azure portal I can see that the endpoint for

- Bing Search is `https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0`
- Bing Custom Search is `https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bingcustomsearch/v7.0`

So it is indeed using `Bing Search` as opposed to `Bing Custom Search` but the version number is incorrect `7.0` vs `5.0`. I have fixed that in the code.
And now the `"BingSearch"` in  `ServiceConnect` works!

See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/bing-web-upgrade-guide-v5-to-v7